# The status of the transaction

Tags: transactions

I send 0.00528479 BTC to the address 1HkqAUTgCgnnMP1CconWudxWAT3fMVpLtw with network fee of 0.0001 BTC. i checked the status and i dont know whether confirmed or not. one shows in green colour and one shows in red Color. kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoins were received by the address and then spent, leaving the address with no balance. It appears both transactions are confirmed.

Comment: what need to be done to get it back?

Comment: Was the payment made in error? If so, you'll need to ask the recipient for a refund.